# Hive LIKE query returns some like results, several unlike results, and some NULL results

Tags: hive

When I queried from hive with 'LIKE', it looks like

```
select * from table where a_column like '%http%';
```

It returns me some results where a_column does not contain `http` and some `NULL` results.

I want to know whether my query sentence is serious or not.

Is there any pattern more seriously?

Comment: Such behavior can be if a_column contains tab characters '\t', then it works correctly but being displayed tabs causing columns shift and it can look like null or if tab is in the middle of the string it splits string and shift it partially in the next column.

Comment: I don't think that a_column contains '\t', in addition, the results are checked one by one but not checked in that list result.

Answer (score 0):

Please use in the below way using concat_ws.

select * from table where concat_ws(',',map_values(a_column)) like '%http%';

Comment: I'm sorry but 'map_values' requires a Map type as the parameter but a_column is a string. So it runs failed.

Comment: Okay. Let me  try other options and will update the answer accordingly.